# flutter - How do shadow behind two container with border radius (curved\clipped card)

Tags: flutter

What me need and what i have:
[curved shadow card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyPe.png)

I tried put shadow in parent but the not correct. Shadow between container must be rounded.

This is how the code looks:

```
Container(
      width: 396,
      height: 128,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 120,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                  offset: Offset(0, 2),
                  blurRadius: 5,
                ),
              ],
            ),

          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    blurRadius: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve `shadow` in container this way:

example1:

```
Container(
          height: 128,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 120,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                    width: 4,
                  ),
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                child: Center(child: Text('Container 1')),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                      width: 4,
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text('Container 2')),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

example1_Result:

[image]

example2:

```
body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 128,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                  width: 4,
                ),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                    offset: Offset(0, 2),
                    blurRadius: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 120,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Container 1')),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Center(child: Text('Container 2')),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),            
        ),
```

Example2_Result:

[image]

example3:

```
body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 128,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                        offset: Offset(0, 2),
                        blurRadius: 5,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ClipPath(
                  clipper: CurveClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 128,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      boxShadow: const [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                        ),
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Color(0x4C0DCBED),
                          offset: Offset(0, 2),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 120,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          child: const Center(child: Text('Container 1')),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: const Center(child: Text('Container 2')),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path()
      ..lineTo(0, size.height - 10)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 10)
      ..lineTo(size.width, 0)
      ..close();

    final topPath = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height - 10)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height - 10);

    final bottomPath = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height - 10)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height - 20, 0, size.height - 10)
      ..close();

    path.addPath(topPath, Offset.zero);
    path.addPath(bottomPath, Offset.zero);

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

example3_result:

[image]

Comment: Example2 is similar, but not what I need. At the junction, the shadow should be rounded. I edited example image.